# Removing first and last punctuation from python

Tags: python, list, punctuation

I have the following problem, I want to remove the punctuation marks at the beginning and at the end but leave the ones in between.
Example. \

```
[':Hamburger{', 'word>', 'don´t', 'isn´t,']
```

and this should turn

```
['Hamburger', 'word', 'don´t', 'isn´t']
```

So if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this. Just `import re` at the start of the file, then you could use the following line to replace all punctuation and the start or end of the line:

```
for el in list:
    el = re.sub("^[^\w\s]|[^\w\s]$", "", el)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` module has a predefined string of common punctuation characters:

```
>>> from string import punctuation as punct
>>> punct
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Which you can use in combination with `str.strip` to strip each of your strings:

```
>>> "<>.,.,.!TEST<>>..]}".strip(punct)
'TEST'
```

---

```
def make_pretty(word):
    from string import punctuation as punct
    return word.strip(punct)

words = [':Hamburger{', 'word>', 'don´t', 'isn´t,']

print(list(map(make_pretty, words)))
```

Output:

```
['Hamburger', 'word', 'don´t', 'isn´t']
```

That being said, `string.punctuation` is not exhaustive. The character `´`, for example, is not present, and therefore wouldn't be stripped.